# Are trivial edits considered which don't make any impact?

Tags: discussion, edits, trivial

As soon as I logged in SO, I was quite surprised to see the **edit** that was suggested to my answer which has been answered few months ago. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035740/1592160) is what I am talking about.

The edit was just a deletion of a `character(;)`. Of course I very much encourage and like constructive edits, but I don't think this is a constructive edit. If you don't feel that this isn't a constructive edit, please don't get me wrong. I am just curious about the thing that how it has been accepted as an edit. Because as far as I know, the edits should be reviewed for the approval/rejection and the trivial edits get rejected. so, how basically the edits rejection and approvals are based on? If this is the case that a person who has 2000+ rep doesn't need an approval for his/her edit, then what if in case he deleted a crucial code line or whatever minor character in the coding answer?

[image]

Comment: How old was your question before it was edited?  Is it possible the editor was going for the Archaeologist badge?  EDIT: Just checked; looks like your answer didn't qualify for 6 months yet.

Comment: @JoshDM: Your thinking about  badge was great. Even I earned that but it was by luck, never tried to find a question that was buried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said with 2k+ you can edit everything. No review is necessary then. But still minor edits are discouraged because it pushes the question in the *active-questions* queue.

In this case I am torn. It is minor but it highlights the code segment. I would have rejected (or improved) it in a review and would not change it myself with 2k+ rep, but that is just me.

Comment: Well, I had a reason to be not highlighted it as a code, because I have given an extra information over there which the OP didn't mention that he needed it :) BTW it's just a method which had no impact in the actual answer that I have given.

Comment: If you feel the edit was incorrect then you can revert it. That is why you get notified about edits on your posts - to see if they were fine.

Comment: No, actually I am not bothered about his edit nor him gaining a rep. But I really wonder how come it is considered as a constructive edit. I am even surprised with the answer which takes his side.

Comment: Over 2k you are not getting any rep for edits.

Comment: @Appu: As you said you are not bothered to revert, this gives the answer "The edit is constructive". Lets say if the edit was something non-sense, you must have reverted it, and then it was said as non-constructive.

Comment: Well, I already mentioned. That doesn't make any difference for me either whether he gains a rep or not.

Comment: I mean I couldn't find any revert feature in the notification that I have received. Am I missing it?

Comment: No, your are only getting notified about the edit. When you view the revision history of your post there is a rollback link where you can undo the edit.

Comment: @juergend +1 Okay. It says something like sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any offensive votes. If I rollback it, I think it might be considered as a trivial rollback, isn't it? :P

Comment: Rolling back a revision does not *mean anything*. It is just rolled back. it does not have any impact on the editor nor you. You can roll it back if you like. Nothing more happens.

Answer (score 4):

Ragunath Jawahar found your answer and noticed that closeContextMenu() is a code snippet, which should be `closeContextMenu()`.

So he changed it.

And he has 4K reputation, which means this edit was not suggested, and it was not reviewed.  So you can not say he changed only for getting 2 reputation points from this as he received none.

Comment: If it had been in the Suggested Edit queue, I would have voted to reject it for being "too minor", whereupon it would have still been approved by three other people anyways.

Comment: @LBT: i would have approved :)

Comment: Sigh, I really, really wish, LBT's comment could have been sarcasm, but Anoop is verifying that it's still truth.

Comment: Which is why I gave up on the queue a long time ago

Comment: I said I don't think this is a constructive edit. Come on! Do you think a closeContextMenu() would make a much more sense than closeContextMenu();? Programmers will know about this triviality.

Comment: @Appu The *primary* change is enclosing the code snippet in code blocks, not the removal of the semi-colon, so it's not quite *that* trivial.

Comment: @Appu: using code-style text counts. It flashes to eyes...doesn't?
If you think this as a trivial, you have the right to rollback or edit.

Comment: Even if the edit is a completely trivial one that wouldn't be accepted in the queue, IMO it shouldn't be reverted unless it makes the question actually worse.

Answer (score 3):

I make edits like this all the time. I'll always scan for other things wrong with the formatting/grammar, and will always try to fix those at the same time, however.

I don't recommend that users who cannot get edits approved immediately do this, but once you've reached sufficient reputation, it is fine to make smaller edits. That said, this should be balanced with an awareness that editing pushes something to the front page, so I won't do cosmetic edits often. In any case, there is a *huge* amount of posts that are badly formatted and have terrible grammar, which are much more deserving of an editor's pen!

For what it's worth, the Stack Exchange sites are used by people who vary substantially in their attitudes to incorrect spelling, grammar, punctuation and formatting. Speaking personally, my attitude is somewhere on the "undiagnosed OCD" spectrum, and so an unformatted line of code inside written prose, for me, stands out like a sore thumb<sup>1</sup>. Other people have a brain that is wired differently, and it skips over spelling mistakes and text-speak without registering it consciously.

Long story short: if a post is improved, and the editor responsible is not pushing large numbers of minor edits in a short time frame, then it's fine, even if you personally would not have bothered with the same changes.

<sup>1</sup> If this question was on Stack Overflow, I would split your second paragraph into two separate paragraphs to make it easier for subsequent readers to parse. Trivial perhaps, but if it makes reading easier, it's worthwhile `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't accepted as an edit. The user who edited your answer had the [edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) privilege, so his edit didn't need to go through the peer review system.

Now about the edit itself. If an edit makes a question or answer better then it is a good edit. The main reason users with less than 2k reputation are discouraged from making minor edits is because it takes up precious reviewer time to review these edits. Users with more than 2,000 reputation can make whatever edits they want.

You point out that this could cause problems, and it sometimes does. Issues that arise out of users abusing their edit privilege are usually spotted and corrected quickly and the moderators have plenty of tools for dealing with abusive users.

All in all I don't think there was any issue here.

Comment: That said, even users with edit privileges are encouraged to make substantial edits and not very minor ones, just not quite as strongly.

Comment: Aside from taking up reviewers time there is another reason why trivial edits are discouraged and that is what [juergen d](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011/juergen-d) mentioned that it pushes it into the active-questions queue.